# Performance under structure packing in C

Tags: c, gcc

I am using a 64bit machine

When using the structure

```
 typedef struct node{
    unsigned int p; //4 bytes
    struct node* next;//8bytes
 }Node;
 //sizeof(Node) is 16 bytes
```

I know that this is due to structure padding. 
If I use structure packing using

```
typedef struct __attribute__((__packed__))
//sizeof(Node) is 12 bytes
```

Should I expect any performance degradation using packing or is it system dependent?

Compiler is `gcc (GCC) 4.4.7`

I have tested my code with packed and unpacked structure and there doesn't seem to be any difference in the performance.

Comment: If you are compiling a 64-bit application, I'm surprised that `unsigned int` is 32-bit.

Comment: @JimBuck: `unsigned int` is 32-bits on many 64-bit platforms, including  both Windows and Linux.  On the other hand, `unsigned long` is 64-bits on Linux and still 32-bits on Windows. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/64-bit_computing

Comment: Gah, really?? That's a bit of a surprise since I thought `int` was meant to target the register size. Now I've got to review some previously-written code to be sure it's not taken by surprise. :)

Comment: @ma08 - There should be some degradation - if there weren't, the compiler would have no reason to add padding. The question is how much.  And it's certainly system dependent - on some processors the access to non-aligned members will require multiple loads and shifts to read the unaligned member. I'd guess it's not worth doing unless & until you *know* you need the space savings.

Comment: @MichaelBurr I definitely need the space savings as I am working with huge amounts of data (cryptographic attack). As for the performance, so far I haven't seen any degradation.

Comment: A different improvement idea - if you only have 2^32 Nodes and all of them are in one array, you can drop the pointer and use the index as unsigned int field. You're going to save 4 bytes and your whole structure will fit in 8 bytes by default.

Comment: @viraptor great idea :) but I was thinking of increasing it to 2^33 nodes as I was saving space with the packing. If I run it only on 2^32 nodes, then I will definitely use your idea

Comment: @viraptor even for 2^32 nodes I will be missing out a null value, so I guess that won't work.

Comment: @ma08 do you ever need to do a circular reference? if not then you can treat self-index as NULL (nodes[current].next==current)

Comment: @viraptor ha, that's clever!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not a lot of information. The answer will also depends on your Node allocation strategy, on whether you embed the node in your data or store it separately, on how big your cache lines are, what kind of work you do, etc.

Measure your runtime with and without packing (in your specific application) - you'll have the answer.

Comment: I am allocating large number of nodes using malloc(around 2^32 nodes at once). I am not embedding the nodes anywhere. Yeah I am currently trying to measure it. I don't know exactly what information is helpful to give a good answer. I can give you further specifics if it helps.

Comment: What I meant is that we're unlikely to give you more information than you can give us. Measure it and see for yourself. I can only give you an educated guess that packing will give you worse performance if you malloc() each node separately, because each alloced block will likely be at least 8-bytes aligned. If you malloc() a single block and stuff Node objects end-to-end like an array, it may be faster.

Comment: Yeah I am using the latter type of allocation(array) to make it faster. Right now, performance seems to be the same as per my tests. So I guess it is better to go with packing due to the lower memory usage.

Comment: @ma08 You can also check your code with valgrind with cachegrind tool - it will tell you if your cache hit rates changed at all with packing. If you get really low hit rates, maybe some reordering of nodes will give you bigger gain than just the packing.

Comment: Yeah I will do some analysis using valgrind.